# Summarise char columns in R

Tags: r

My data is like

```
  Part   Supplier
1  A      P
2  A      Q
3  B      R
4  B      S
5  B      T
6  C      U
7  C      V
8  C      W
9  C      X
```

desired output

```
  Part   Supplier
1 A      P,Q 
2 B      R,S,T
3 C      U,V,W,X
```

please suggest

Answer (score 0):

We can use `aggregate` to `paste` the 'Supplier' for each 'Part'

```
aggregate(Supplier ~ Part, df1, toString)
#    Part   Supplier
#1    A       P, Q
#2    B    R, S, T
#3    C U, V, W, X
```

---

Or with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
    group_by(Part) %>%
    summarise(Supplier = toString(Supplier))
```

Or some versions

```
df1 %>% 
    group_by(Part) %>%
    summarise(Supplier = paste(Supplier, collapse = ", ))
```

If there are more than one column

```
df1 %>%
     group_by(Part) %>%
     summarise_if(is.character, toString)
```

---

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, .(Supplier = toString(Supplier)), .(Part)]
```